# Manual ordering of categorical variables in ggplot is changed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I manually re-ordered my categories as:

```
bite_anatomy_other_variables <- bite_anatomy_other_variables %>% 
   mutate(species = fct_relevel(species,
                                "Pet dog" , "Unowned dog" , "Dog (unknown status)",
                                "Pet cat" , "Unowned cat" , "Cat (unknown status)",
                                "Rat/rodent" , "Monkey" , "Livestock (cattle/goat/sheep/pig/horse)"))
```

Then when I make a plot with the code below, the order changes

```
bite_anatomy_other_variables %>%
  filter(!(species %in% c("Monkey", "Livestock (cattle/goat/sheep/pig/horse)"))) %>%
  add_count(species) %>%
  mutate(species = factor(species, levels = species_order)) %>%
  mutate(species = paste0(species, "\n", "(n = ", n, ")")) %>% # THIS CODE CREATES ISSUES
  ggplot(mapping = aes(y = species, fill = body_part_collapsed)) +
  geom_bar(colour = "black", position = "fill") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = c("0", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")) +
  labs(x = "Proportion of responses", y = "Animal species") +
  ggtitle("Body part exposed")
```

The manual order stayed the intended way when I did not use the "mutate(species = paste0(species, "\n", "(n = ", n, ")")) %>%"

Now when I use the above code, the order changes, and I can't seem to return it back. Can you help me with showing the graph in my desired category order?

[Undesired order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwdzg.png)

[Desired order but with the "(n = xxx)" in the y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biXTN.png)

Comment: `mutate(species = fct_relevel(species, ...)` puts the levels in one order that you specify. Then, later you use `mutate(species = factor(species, levels = species_order)` which puts them in the `species_order` order. You haven't shared `species_order`, so we don't know if it's the same or different. Then `mutate(species = paste0(species, "\n", "(n = ", n, ")"))` makes all of the above moot because `paste0` returns a `character`, not a `factor`. I would suggest deleting the `paste0` line, and keeping only one of the `relevel`  or `species_order` lines.

Comment: I can't delete the paste0 since that gives me the (n=xxx) on the y-axis of my graph. How can I have the order as well as the counts of the categories in the y-axis?

Comment: Create that only for the plot labels in `scale_y_discrete`, using the `labels` argument. If you make your example reproducible by sharing some sample data we can try to demonstrate. The nicest way to share sample data is with `dput()` because it is copy/pasteable, e.g., `dput(bite_anatomy_other_variables[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows.

Comment: Can you let me know how do I create this for the plot labels?

here is the dput() output:

structure(list(species = structure(c(1L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 7L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Pet dog", "Unowned dog", "Dog (unknown status)", 
"Pet cat", "Unowned cat", "Cat (unknown status)", "Rat/rodent", 
"Monkey"), class = "factor"), body_part_collapsed = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 4L), levels = c("", "arm/hand", 
"Back", "legs/thigh", "Glutes / Butt region", "Head/neck/face", 
"Trunks (front)"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A labeler (as I suggested in comments) won't actually work so easily since it requires input from another column. Instead, I create a new factor with the annotations and use `reorder` to match the manually ordered version:

```
bite_anatomy_other_variables %>%
  filter(!(species %in% c("Monkey", "Livestock (cattle/goat/sheep/pig/horse)"))) %>%
  add_count(species) %>%
  mutate(y_species = 
    reorder(
      factor(paste0(species, "\n", "(n = ", n, ")")),
      as.numeric(species)
  )) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(y = y_species, fill = body_part_collapsed)) +
  geom_bar(colour = "black", position = "fill") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = c("0", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")) +
  labs(x = "Proportion of responses", y = "Animal species") +
  ggtitle("Body part exposed")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This absolutely works. You just made my whole day.

I have one more question regarding this. In a situation where we use facet_wrap with a third categorical variable, how can we show the "(n = xxx)" for each faceted graph?

Comment: That's quite a bit trickier. I would suggest asking a new question with a reproducible example.